# Regex match line containing string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will select an entire line where it contains a matching string.

I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the expression:

```
^.*?(\bEventname 2\b).*$
```

You can see the test case and what I've tried here:

https://www.regex101.com/r/mT5rZ3/1

Comment: What about `.*Eventname 2.*`.

Comment: you forget to put m modifier. https://www.regex101.com/r/mT5rZ3/2

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why add multi-line modifier if OP only wants to match single lines?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I see it working in regex101 but in my software (uBot Studio) it doesn't. Don't think I can use m modifier there, but thanks for the try :-)

Comment: Actually I got you solution @m0skit0 to work by first filtering my search string to only use the code in parenthesis as it was unique and made it easier to match... Thanks!

Answer (score 54):

here's what I use and it works perfectly for me

```
^.*substring.*$
```

Answer (score 29):

This answer solves the question with 463 steps instead of 952 steps. Just ensure a new line at the end of the file.

`.*Eventname 2.*\n`

https://www.regex101.com/r/mT5rZ3/5

###### EDIT 4-9-2022

With `.*Eventname 2.*\n?` it also solves with 463 steps, but there is no need to ensure a new line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the PHP regex . don't match newlines. So

```
.*(\bEventname 2\b).*
```

would be enough. If . matches newline you would need *? to make the dots non-greedy (so it just matches one line, instead of everything). You also need to be in multi-line mode to use ^ and $, but that shouldn't be necessary (since you only want to match one line anyway).

Comment: My search string would be like: Eventname 2 (T104) - can't seem to get it to work like that... ?

Comment: .*(\bEventname 2 \(T104\)).*

Skip the word boundry, since it's already ended with ). You also need to escape the ().

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
(.*(?:Eventname 2).*)
```

explaination:

`(` ... `)` : groups and captures the line

`(?:`...`)` : groups without capturing the string that the line needs to contain

`.*` : any characters

Answer (score 2):

You are using a *string* containing several *lines*. By default, the `^` and `$` operators will match the beginning and end of the whole string. The `m` modifier will cause them to match the beginning and end of a line.